# Make an image in an li disappear with hover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

Trying to make an `img` in a `li` to hide when mouse hovers over element and to show once mouse leaves element.
I later want to have a paragraph display the name of the li class in place of the image but I want to focus on the image hiding for now.

I've been messing with this for a while and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong even after looking at other posts related to this.

```
<ul id="language">
    <li class="a"><img src="img/a.png" alt="a"></li>
    <li class="b"><img src="img/b.png" alt="b"></li>
</ul>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="nameDisplay.js" type = "text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

In nameDisplay.js

```
$('#language li').hover(function(){
    $(this 'img').hide();
}, function(){
    $(this 'img').show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use css, no need to use jQuery

```
#language li:hover img{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to add a <p> while the mouse hovers the img using css? Because thats the next step I'm taking

Comment: what do you want to display in the `p` element

Comment: @asdkhalifa Yes you can :) insert <p> into <li> with "display: none" then on li:hover p use "display:block"

Comment: Okay! When I used the code you suggested with :hover, the element would  flicker rather than just disappear until the mouse left the element

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#language li').hover(function() {
    $('img', this).hide();
    // You can either of these 
    // $(this).find('img') 
    // $(this).children('img') 
  }, function() {
    $('img', this).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<ul id="language">
  <li class="a">
    <img src="img/a.png" alt="a">
  </li>
  <li class="b">
    <img src="img/b.png" alt="b">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your selector to find image is incorrect. You can use context selector or `.find()` or `children()` method

```
$(function() {
    $('#language li').hover(function(){
        $('img', this).hide();
        // You can either of these 
        // $(this).find('img') 
        // $(this).children('img') 
    }, function(){
        $('img', this).show();
    });
});
```